# Insert NaN if key not in dictionary in else condition in list comprehension when creating new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, null, list-comprehension

I want to populate a column in pandas data frame of a set length with values from a dictionary using a list comprehension.

The dictionary maps keys that correspond to *almost all* unique values from an existing column of the data frame to some values. Crucially, not all of the unique values are included in the dictionary. In those cases, I would like to place the pandas-native null value, NaN. This way my new list can be of the same length as the column in the data frame.

I have tried using an if-else structure in the list comprehension, as follows:

```
df['col_B'] = [d[key] for key in df['col_A'].values if key in d else NaN]
```

I expect to get a fully populated column with NaN for rows where there was no key-value pair in the dictionary. But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am aware that the error lies in the else part of the statement, but I do not know how to specify that part so that it inserts NaN for the missing key-value pairs.

Here is a toy example that reproduces the error:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd

# create a dictionary
d = {1:'a',2:'b', 3:'c'}  

# create a list
data = [2,1,3,1,4,2,2,1,4,3]

# Create a data drame with list as only column
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['number']) 

# add new column by populating list with matching dictionary values
df['letter'] = [d[key] for key in df['number'] if key in d else NaN]
```

Comment: can you add a full [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? so that we dont have to create a dummy data for you

Comment: Would you like add some sample data  ?

Comment: Simply change the order: `[d[key] if key in d else NaN for key in df['col_A'].values]`

Comment: `df['number'].map(d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `map` here

```
df['letter']=df.number.map(d)
df
   number letter
0       2      b
1       1      a
2       3      c
3       1      a
4       4    NaN
5       2      b
6       2      b
7       1      a
8       4    NaN
9       3      c
```